# How to remove items from listbox

Tags: c#, listbox

i tried to remove item from listbox using MultiExtended as selection mode
this is my code

im using this snippet code for getid from listbox

```
private int getid(int index)
{
    int.TryParse(lb_ItemList.Items[lb_ItemList.SelectedIndices[index]].ToString().Split('-')[0], out index);
    return index;
}
```

and this code im using for remove index from listbox

```
        for (int i = lb_ItemList.Items.Count - 1; i > -1; i--)
        {
            lb_ItemList.Items.RemoveAt(lb_ItemList.SelectedIndices[getid(i)]);
        }
```

but for any reason it doesn't work... any suggestion? thanks

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! `but for any reason it doesn't work`, can you please expand with further details and clarity of what doesn't work?

Comment: hi, thanks you for your answer, i just took a screenshot of the error https://prnt.sc/WvGqIpYVIODx

Comment: So many thing wrong this this code.  How about you start over, explaining in plain English what is supposed to happen.  Show us what is in the ListBox, what getid() is supposed to retrieve, and what the ListBox should look like after removing things.

Comment: ...and the screenshot doesn't even match your code.

Comment: so int getid(int index) is getting index from selected index in listbox and the loop is for remove the selected ITEMS(indexs) with MultiExtended in listbox but the code for remove selected items from listbox doesn't work it always give me error as i show in the picture, i could do lb_Itemlist.Items.RemoveAt(lb_Itemlist.SelectedIndex) but doing this way only will remove 1 selected index instead of all i multi selected

Comment: That really doesn't clear up what you want to happen.  Why is `getid()` splitting and parsing the text version of the entry?  You are mixing loops, collections, and `i`s.  In the first loop, you are using `lb_ItemList.Items.Count - 1` down to `0` which gives you EVERY index for ALL the items in the ListBox in reverse order.  Then you pass that `i` number to `getid()` but are using it with `lb_ItemList.SelectedIndices[index]`.  The `i` value from the first loop (spanning all indices) is not going to necessarily correspond to the collection representing the collection of only SELECTED items.

Comment: Are you trying to only operate on items that are currently selected?...or all items?  The two thing don't go together.  How does the `ToString().Split('-')[0]` come into play?  Show us some PICTURES of the ListBox so we can see what is literally in it, along with what is currently selected.  Then show us what you want removed (with WHY), and a picture of the final ListBox with the items removed.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you need to copy the content of `lb_ItemList.SelectedIndices` before you start remove items out of `lb_ItemList` because every call to `Remove(...)` will update the content of `lb_ItemList.SelectedIndices`

Answer (score 0):

You only need remove by index and SelectedIndices has the index:

```
for (int i = lb_ItemList.SelectedIndices.Count - 1; i > -1; i--)
{
    var index = lb_ItemList.SelectedIndices[i];
    lb_ItemList.Items.RemoveAt(index);
}
```

You don't need your Id to remove selected items.

If you need work with you class in the Items, I recomended you create an Item class:

```
public class YourItem
{
    public YourItem()
    {
    }

    public YourItem(int id, string name)
    {
        this.Id = id;
        this.Name = name;
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{this.Id} - {this.Name}";
    }
}
```

Then, you add your items to the ListBox:

```
this.lb_ItemList.Items.Add(new YourItem(1, "A"));
this.lb_ItemList.Items.Add(new YourItem(2, "B"));
this.lb_ItemList.Items.Add(new YourItem(3, "C"));
this.lb_ItemList.Items.Add(new YourItem(4, "D"));
```

The text of each item is that you return in ToString method of YourItem. For example "1 - A" for the first item.

And, when you are working with the ListBox, simply cast to your class:

```
var item = (YourItem)this.lb_ItemList.Items[1];
var id = item.Id;
var name = item.Name;
```

If you class is big, you can use your Item as a wrapper:

```
public class YourClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    // Other properties, methods...
}

public class YourItem
{
    private YourClass _item;

    public YourItem(YourClass obj)
    {
        this._item = obj;
    }

    public int Id
    {
        get { return this._item.Id}
        set { this._item.Id = value; }
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return this._item.Name}
        set { this._item.Name = value; }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{this.Id} - {this.Name}";
    }
}
```

Your class maybe have lost of information but for your item, you only expose Id and Name, for example.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. I still tried your solution but i always get this error when im triying to remove items from listbox System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: 'Se produjo una excepción en el destino de la invocación.' ArgumentOutOfRangeException: InvalidArgument=El valor de '-1' no es válido para 'index'.
Nombre del parámetro: index im using listbox and multiextend  as selection mode..

Comment: It's strange. Microsoft's documentation doesn't say anything, but in my tests, SelectedIndices has the indexes that are selected in order. That is, if you go through that list in reverse, they are removed in order. My code does not generate any exception and works as expected. Can you debug the loop in which you delete the items? Do you have any associated ListBox event that may be affecting, that does something when items are deleted?

Comment: i just record a video of my bug, maybe yo can find it out.. https://youtu.be/tculuqFoTbU

Comment: I can't see the video

Comment: I just realized that I had a problem in my function getid() that's why always my tool was crashing. So basically your answer helped me Victor, thanks you!